# Using PDO statements instead of mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am learning PDO statements so as for better security to Database. I read somewhere that mysql_* functions will be going to deprecated completely. So, to avoid any kind of mishap to web application, i am shifting to PDO statements.

I want my already written mysql_* statements in PDO statements.

1. I have written connection to DB as

   ```
   try {

   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password);

   echo 'Connected to database';
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
   ```

   Que1: Now, can i not make this file as a common file to connect to DB and include it in any page i want to.

   Que2: If i can use this as a common file then is it necessary to include mysql statements in "try" block.

My approach is to use this as a common file and use mysql PDO statements on any page i want.

Comment: Go and Learn more about PDO please

Comment: Ans.1. Yes, you can add this db-connection code to a common file and include wherever you need.
Ans.2. If you are using `PDO` then you don't have to use `mysql_*` `mysqli_*` at all. What is need of mixing `PDO` with `mysql_` statements?

Comment: thanks @Log1c .. i want to use this as one common file and rest statements for fetching DB values should be included in the page that i want to. i am not usign **mysql** statements but i want to convert **mysql** statements to prepared statements

Comment: hi  samitha.. Can you help me with tutorial link that well explains PDO statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the exactly such a case I wrote my [PDO wrapper](https://github.com/colshrapnel/thebestpdowrapper).

All you need is to edit configuration constants and include this file in some bootstrap file. **That's all.** And immediately it will let you to use PDO as easy as mysql_* used to be (as long as you have this file included), yet with full power and safety of prepared statements. Or even simpler than old mysql ext, as most operations will be written in one-two lines.

There are still two main differences from old mysql ext:

- instead of calling `mysql_query` you have to call `DB::prepare()`
- instead of adding variables in the query directly you have to pass them in `execute()` and substitute them in the query with question marks.

Here are some usage examples

```
// with one variable
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=?";
$user = DB::prepare($sql)->execute([$_POST['name']])->fetch();

// with two variables
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age > ? and skill = ?";
$user = DB::prepare($sql)->execute([$age, $skill])->fetch();

// without variables and getting more than one rows
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC";
$user = DB::prepare($sql)->execute()->fetchAll();

//insert with getting insert id
$sql  = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)";
$user = DB::prepare($sql)->execute([$name,$pass,$email])->fetch();
$id   = DB::lastInsertId();
```

if you don't know how to use PDO at all, here is a [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) with basic usage examples.

In short, you have to run your queries in three steps:

- prepare
- execute
- fetch

using my wrapper they all can be chained. See an example

And of course you have to follow the main rule of creating SQL statements: **every variable should go into query via placeholder only**

Comment: Great.. Thanks @Your Common Sense ... That is what exactly i was looking for. Now can you let me know what if i have more than one parameter to be included in Where clause and how to implement it for showing values on HTML page.

Comment: 1. just add more placeholders in prepare and more elements in execute. 2. basically you have to know how to handle arrays. Examples can be found by the link to tag wiki i provided

Comment: So, is it like `$sql  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=? and place=?";`
`$user = DB::prepare($sql)->execute([$_POST['name']],[$_POST['place']])->fetch();`   and how can i use this statemnt to print values as we used to in mysql_* i.e. $row['column_name'];

Comment: tht i will change @Your Common Sense.. I meant to say there `$user['column_nme']` nd even i was nt sure that $user van b used as same as $row... Thanks for your help

Comment: Will your wrapper work for other databases too.. Like oracle or postgrage sql

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include it as a common `include` file that your other scripts use. However, it's probably not a good idea to have include files print anything, because they might be used by scripts that have special requirements on what they print. For instance, if it's used by an AJAX script that returns JSON, printing an error message will result in invalid JSON.

A compromise would be to put the code into a function, and it could take a parameter that specifies whether it should print an error message.

Comment: Hi @Barmar .. i want to convert mysql statements to prepared statements.. can you help me with good tutorial link for PDO?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know any tutorials.